# access runtime error in different time zone

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have this application in access 2016, back end sqlexpress 2008, running in access runtime 2013 (runtime 2016 won't install). It works fine.

I tried to use it in Japan, different time zone connected via vpn, link tables to Hong Kong database. Tables connect successfully. When i open a form with a default date, the field returns error, but if I go into the field and type out the date, it works. Date format functions causes error...

When I change the time zone in Japan to Hong Kong time zone, everything works...

Help and advice needed to overcome the issue, many thanks in advance.

It is normal when loading a few records but significantly slows down for more records. So, any other options to work the database from overseas?

Thank you in advance

Richard

Comment: Well, somehow you set the (default)value of that field in a not proper way. But what do we know?

Comment: Hi Gustav. i set the default value as Date()

Comment: Try, when opening the form, to set _DefaultValue_ to the string from: `"#" & Format(Date, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"`.

Comment: Hi Gustav. Many thanks for your suggestion. Will try it out.